# Why do I need to use "hard" specifications for the second part of the slide in this frame?

Tags: beamer, uncover, only

Working with Beamer, I sometimes found this issue that I am not sure how to handle.
When I want to show within a frame first an enumeration uncovered piecewise, and then another one occupying the same space, I use the command `\only` combined with lists uncovered piecewise with the `[<+->]` code.

And the first `\only` command behaves as I expect, uncovering the slides as is placed inside the `\only` with whatever code that I use to control the overlay.
The problem comes with the second time that `\only` appears. Then, I need to "hardcode" the slides using numeric references to the slides if I want piecewise uncover, or any control over the slides uncovering.

The example of this frame explains this:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, 14pt]{beamer} %Presentation

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Title of the frame}

\begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
    Here it goes something
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.40\textwidth}
    \only<1-3>{Hello: \\
    
    \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
    \item one slide
    \item 2 slide
    \item 3 slide
    \end{enumerate}}%End of \only<1-3>
    \only<4->{
    in the same place
    
    \begin{enumerate}%[<+->]
    \item<4-> 4 slide
    \item<5-> 5 slide
    \item<6-> laast slide
    \end{enumerate}
    }%End of \only<4-
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is this an expected behaviour? Because to me sounds like I am doing something wrong, not being able to use `[<+->]`after the first `\only`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is that `\only` does not typeset its content and then throws it away. Instead, it just throws it away. That is, on slide four, the content of `\only<1-3>` is never executed, so `beamerpauses` is never incremented. Thus, with `\begin{enumerate}[<+->]`, the first `\item` will still be equivalent to `\item<1->` etc. This is why all three items are shown on slide 4. You can see this more clearly if you add more items to the second list: Only the first four will be shown on slide 4, the others will be shown incrementally.

One solution is to just say `\setcounter{beamerpauses}{4}` after `\only<4->{`, "faking" the incrementation of the omitted first list.

A possibly preferable possibility is to use `overprint` instead.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title of the frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<1-3>
      Hello:
    
      \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
        \item one slide
        \item 2 slide
        \item 3 slide
      \end{enumerate}%
    
    \onslide<4->
      in the same place
      
      \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
      \item 4 slide
      \item 5 slide
      \item laast slide
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I seem to remember having some trouble with `overprint` in complex slide layouts, so it's still good to have the `beamerpauses` hack in your back pocket. But as long as it works, I'd go with `overprint`.